# angular2 How to store response header data from http.get in extra variable?

Tags: http, angular, get, header, response

I'm quite new to Angular 2 and Typescript and want to build a Card-Search App. 
Basically I have a component where the response data is stored and observed...

```
this.searchFormGroup.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(searchFormGroup => this.mtgService.getCardsByName(searchFormGroup))
    .subscribe(
      searchResult => { 
        this.searchResult = searchResult.cards;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

...and a service, which sends the http.get request to the API ...

```
getCardsByName(searchFormGroup){
   this.params.set(...) ...

   return this.http.get(this.nameUrl, { search: this.params })
     .map(res => res.json())
     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))}
```

... communicating with each other.

What's the best way to store header-data from the request inside the component? Basically I need the total card-count and paging-links of the request, which are available inside the response header. I've been trying to find a solution to this for hours :o

Comment: What headers do you need?

Comment: Link:, Page-Size, Count, Total-Count, Ratelimit-Limit and Ratelimit-Remaining basically. API URL for GET request is https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards for example

Comment: The best way to set the headers on the backend.

Comment: I try to avoid building a backend for now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try and error got me a solution to this problem:
component activated service's http.get -> service responded with res.json() -> component only got res in JSON, what seems to delete the response header.
My workaround is:

Component:

```
this.searchFormGroup.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(searchFormGroup => this.mtgService.getCardsByName(searchFormGroup))
    .subscribe(
      res => { 
        console.log(res.headers); //works fine now!
        this.searchResult = res.json().cards;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Service:

```
getCardsByName(searchFormGroup){
   this.params.set(...) ...

   return this.http.get(this.nameUrl, { search: this.params })
     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')) }
```

So the full res gets passed back to the component now.

However: any tips to make this better?